# How to initialize a class inheriting from an inner class?

Tags: java, constructor, inner-classes

How to initialize a class inheriting from an inner class? Why foo1.this() won't compile?

```
class Foo1 {
    class Inner {
    }
}

class Foo2 extends Foo1.Inner {
    //Foo2(Foo1 foo1) {foo1.this();} //won't compile
    Foo2(Foo1 foo1) {foo1.super();}
}
```

Comment: This seems really smelly. `Foo1.Inner` should probably just be a top-level class.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in an outside class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what `foo1.this();` is supposed to do. Perhaps you are trying to call the default constructor of `Inner`. Since `Inner` is a not a static class, it does not have a no argument constructor. It only looks that way. In reality, it has a constructor which takes a `Foo1` argument containing the reference to its parent object.

The call to `foo1.super()`, however, will work just fine. It will call the constructor of the new `Inner` instance with `foo1` as implicit parent reference. That is, the new `Inner` instance will be tied to the given `Foo1` instance.

As others have pointed out, you can of cause make your `Inner` class static, in which case it does not contain an implicit reference to a `Foo1` instance. Then you can simply call `super();` in your `Foo2` constructor.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer makes a lot of sense. So actually,foo1.super() is calling the Inner's constructor.

Comment: Yes, in the same way `foo1.new Inner()` creates a new `Inner` instance with `foo1` as parent, `foo1.super()` calls the constructor of the new `Inner` instance with `foo1` as parent. It is confusing that it looks like it is a call to the method `super` on `foo1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare the Inner class static you can do it else you need an instance of the outer class Foo1.

```
class Foo1 {
    static class Inner {
    }
}
```

But your direct questions seems strange:

```
foo1.this(); //won't compile
```

What are you trying to do here?
Call a method called "this" it looks like, but hoping to use the no-argument constructor perhaps? Just use `this()` if so.

Comment: When you have an inner class, not nested (static), that class is living in the scope of the outer (two instances of the outer class have two different inner classes, even though the look/named the same). So you have a constructor with the outer class instance as the parameter. That is how you can "reach" (qualify) to reach the parent inner class constructor. Just writing `super`won't work as there is a level of indirection as you are sub classing.

Comment: You could create the parent instance in the subclass as well instead of having it as a constructor parameter, but then it sounds like you could just use a nested (static) class instead. `new Foo1().super();`

Answer (score 0):

Make your inner class `static`. There is no instance from which to get a non static class definition